# Unable to render html template via controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mustache

I am using Spring Boot MVC. I am getting below exception.

```
    com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.exceptions.MustacheTemplateNotFoundException: Mustache template /templates/home.template.html does not exist

        2020-04-17 13:23:40.090 ERROR 25701 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.m.s.v.m.core.DefaultTemplateLoader   : Mustache template '/templates/home.template.html' does not exist, template is not found
2020-04-17 13:23:40.095 ERROR 25701 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.exceptions.MustacheCompilationException: com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.exceptions.MustacheTemplateNotFoundException: Mustache template /templates/home.template.html does not exist] with root cause

com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.exceptions.MustacheTemplateNotFoundException: Mustache template /templates/home.template.html does not exist
        at com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.core.DefaultTemplateLoader.getTemplate(DefaultTemplateLoader.java:150) ~[springmvc-mustache-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.mustachejava.SpringMustacheFactory.getReader(SpringMustacheFactory.java:67) ~[springmvc-mustache-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.mustachejava.MustacheParser.compile(MustacheParser.java:26) ~[compiler-0.9.6.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
        at com.github.mustachejava.DefaultMustacheFactory.compile(DefaultMustacheFactory.java:179) ~[compiler-0.9.6.jar:na]
        at com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.mustachejava.MustacheJavaCompiler.doCompile(MustacheJavaCompiler.java:64) ~[springmvc-mustache-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.core.AbstractMustacheCompiler.compile(AbstractMustacheCompiler.java:68) ~[springmvc-mustache-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.MustacheView.renderTemplate(MustacheView.java:158) ~[springmvc-mustache-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.MustacheView.renderMergedTemplateModel(MustacheView.java:136) ~[springmvc-mustache-0.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:179) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

I have checked the template is there in target folder.

[image]

Below is snippet of my controller.

```
    package com.contentful.demo.controller;

import com.contentful.demo.DemoApplication;
import com.contentful.demo.constants.SystemConstants;
import com.contentful.java.cda.CDAArray;
import com.contentful.java.cda.CDAEntry;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.github.mjeanroy.springmvc.view.mustache.core.ModelAndMustacheView;



@Controller
public class HomePageController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView homePage(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        CDAEntry array = DemoApplication.client
                .fetch(CDAEntry.class)
                .one(SystemConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_HOMEPAGE);
        ModelAndMustacheView view = new ModelAndMustacheView("home");
        view.addObject("home", array);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Folder Strcuture
[image]
How can this fix?

Comment: can you paste full stack trace and full class here, please.

Comment: @Shoshi, Updated with stacktrace

Comment: Did you try to return `ModelAndMustacheView` instead of `ModelAndView` ?

Comment: @Shoshi Yes, I returned ModelAndMustacheView and will be using Mustache to display the content.

Comment: I mean will you try to change the return type from ModelAndView to ModelAndMustacheView? Let me know what happens.

Comment: Also can you confirm your templates folder directory? It should be something like src/main/resources/templates

Comment: @Shoshi Same error, By the way I am using this github reference which is working fine, only difference in this and mine repo is build tool. https://github.com/contentful/product-catalogue-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/contentful/java/starter/Main.java

Comment: can you please check your project with this sample: https://github.com/mjeanroy/springmvc-mustache/tree/master/samples/springmvc-mustache-springboot

Comment: Did you used `@EnableAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: Finally resolved, added a property file and added classpath as mentioned here https://github.com/mjeanroy/springmvc-mustache/commit/9f51e90d6da7de5e3a2bedf9826cf84dd5b812b3#diff-b449bb33d8576d02b1d6c4c0adcba431 Not sure why they removed it.

Comment: wow, glad it resolved. well done :D